# How to align text to pie graph in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, shapes, alignment

I need to align the digits in a pie graph. As usual, I select and clicked center alignment. but it doesn't work. I really want the digits in the center

Do I need to do it manually?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of actually outlining the path, use an outline *Effect*. This allows for non destructive outlining keeping your text editable.

Select the text, then go to **Effect → Path → Outline Object** this will simulate the text as outlined and can then be aligned properly.

Below, I aligned both to the circle, in the second case I first applied the outline effect.

[image: sample]

---

The greatest thing about this case is that you can come back later and very easily change the text all while keeping everything the same (you will have to align them again as the alignment will probably change).

Comment: Thank you so much. did not know about this at all. Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the fonts being used, normal alignment won't always give you the best result. It may help if you center-align the text objects instead of left-align.

Yes, one option is to manually align to get that perfect vertical optical balance.

Otherwise, if you need to be 100% sure, convert the numbers to outlines via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, then centering should be really accurate, because it will treat the numbers as shapes instead of text objects.

Comment: Thankyou. i did it manually  that day  not knowing what should i do it.. now i can try your method.